# How can I limit input to two words max and on-the-fly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an input field for tags. We want to limit tags to at most two words. How can I limit this?

I'm thinking the following, but not sure if there is an easier solution...

- Count spaces. If the user types and then hits a space, assume everything to the left is a word. When the user types again and hits space a second time, assume we have hit two words. The user can no longer type forward, but can backspace to clear out the second word (or the entire input).
- ajax call to a PHP script utilizing str_word_count(). I suppose I can make a call every time the user keydowns, but wouldn't this be overkill? Maybe hit this after every space?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Question sure seems to be asked too early. You should try your ideas and present code when you have problems. That's basically how this site works. This isn't a think tank or sounding board

Comment: Handle it on the client side or you will waste network resources if you communicate to server on each keydown.  Instead restrict the user from the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way with jquery (no server side code)

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qPvch/284/)

```
var maxWords = 2;
jQuery('#txt1').keypress(function() {
    var $this, wordcount;
    $this = $(this);
    wordcount = $this.val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
    if (wordcount > maxWords) {
        alert("Max 2 words please");
        return false;
    } 
});

jQuery('#txt1').change(function() {
    var words = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/);
    if (words.length > maxWords) {
        words.splice(maxWords);
        $(this).val(words.join(""));
        alert("Max 2 words please");
    }
});
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="txt1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be overkill to call a server method each time you make a change when it should be a frontend validation (client side).

It's a common practice to let Javascript handle this kind of validations. You could also add a server validation when you receive data to prevent saving invalid data.

In Javascript, you could add a listener to the input similar to as following:

```
var input_field = document.getElementById('id_of_the_input');
input_field.addEventListener('input', function()
{
  if(input_field.value.split(" ").length > 2){
    alert("You should input only 2 words"); //Change this for a better message
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a a demo showing how to limit words in an input element "on-the-fly". You can adjust the code to accept one or more words by setting the value of `acceptWords`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input').on('input', function () {
    var acceptWords = 2, // Count of words to accept
      boundary = [], // Stores the used word boundary characters
      value = this.value.replace(/\W/g, function (a) { // An array of actual words
        if (--acceptWords > 0) {
          boundary.push(a);
        }
        return ' ';
      }).split(' '),
      finalValue = value[0], // The final value to enter to the input
      n;
    if (boundary.length) { // If word boundary characters found
      for (n = 0; n < boundary.length; n++) {            
        finalValue += boundary[n] + value[n + 1]; // Form a final value
      }
    }
    this.value = finalValue; // Replace the value in the input
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

The code accepts only letters A-Z, a-z, numbers and underscores as a part of a word. If you need to support other characters in an acceptable word, you can modify the regexp accordingly.